# How to send cookies across different domains in production

Tags: express, heroku, next.js, csrf, vercel

***Intro***

My express app is deployed in heroku, and my next js app is deployed in vercel.

I am using csrf protection using 'csurf' package, and everything work in development, but in production the cookies aren't being sent.

After some research I realized that cookies cannot be sent to different domains, but unfortunately I couldn't find a workaround.

**My question**

Is there a way to send and accept cookies from different domains in production? If no, what would you advise me to do?

Thanks in advance

**Things I have tried**

Adding secure and sameSite to csurf:

```
const csrfProtection =csrf({
        cookie: {
          httpOnly: true,
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
          sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax',
        },
});
```

And this is the endpoint for setting the cookie:

```
app.get('/', csrfProtection, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken(), {
    sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax',
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  });

  res.send('success!');
});

app.use(csrfProtection);
```

I also tried the following settings on my express app:

```
const clientOrigin = process.env.CLIENT_ORIGIN || 'http://localhost:3000';

app.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', clientOrigin);
app.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
app.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
app.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, *');

app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.enable('trust proxy');

app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: clientOrigin }));
```

In my next js app i am using a custom axios instance:

```
const axiosInstance = Axios.create({
  baseURL,
  withCredentials: true,
});
```

And this is the code for getting the csrf:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadingAction.setToTrue());
    const getCsrf = async () => {
     await axiosInstance.get('/');
    };
    getCsrf()
      .then(() => {
        dispatch(loadingAction.setToFalse());
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(loadingAction.setToFalse());
        setError(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

The response is successful but no cookies are being set.